# Julia Dot Broadcast and 1 / Vector

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I came across a case that I do not understand while working with Julia:
`1. /` vs `1 ./`

The second and third methods produces what I expect, while the first one does not.
I can also see that the ratios are inverted (i.e. `result1[3] / result[1] = 4.0` while `result2[3] / result2[1] = 0.25`).

I am just curious what the difference is. I know this is `dot broadcasting`, but I was not able to get any traction about this situation.

```
Δx = [2.0, 4.0, 8.0]
result1 = 1. / Δx
result2 = 1 ./ Δx
result3 = 1. ./ Δx

println(result1)  # Output: [0.023809523809523808 0.047619047619047616 0.09523809523809523]
println(result2)  # Output: [0.5, 0.25, 0.125]
println(result3)  # Output: [0.5, 0.25, 0.125]

println(result1[3] / result1[1])    # Output: 4.0
println(result2[3] / result2[1])    # Output: 0.25
```

Update:

```
result1 = 1. /[2.0, 4.0, 8.0]

# Output:
# 1×3 transpose(::Vector{Float64}) with eltype Float64:
#  0.0238095  0.047619  0.0952381

result2 = 1 ./[2.0, 4.0, 8.0]
# Output:
# 3-element Vector{Float64}:
#  0.5
#  0.25
#  0.125
```

Comment: `@code_lowered 1 / [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]` mentions `LinearAlgebra.pinv(v)` as part of the code. does that help?

Comment: That was my guess, the first one might be doing a pseudoinverse of the given 1x3 matrix, but i need to check the docs to be sure. Which is horrible  but makes some sense.

Comment: the type of the "1" doesn't matter. it's purely a difference of `/` vs `./` operators. look at it like this: Julia's `*` on matrices is also defined in terms of linear algebra, not element-wise. the element-wise operators do that. same here.

Comment: Note that in Julia >= v1.9  `1. /[2.0, 4.0, 8.0]` raise an error. The [release notes](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/NEWS/) name exactly this case: "The methods a / b and b \ a with a a scalar and b a vector, which were equivalent to a * pinv(b), have been removed due to the risk of confusion with elementwise division (#44358)."

Comment: must be *after* 1.9.4 because I have 1.9.4 and it's not complaining but giving me the pinv() result

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am using v"1.9.4" on MacOS.
`@code_lowered` is something I will use in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That's very odd.. I am using 1.9.0 on Linux and I do have an error, as from the v1.9 release notes: `julia> VERSION
v"1.9.0"

julia> 1. /[2.0, 4.0, 8.0]
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Float64, ::Vector{Float64})` Are you sure you are using version 1.9.x ?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: ok, got it.. it was removed in v1.9.0 with the conviction that it wasn't breaking, but indeed that change was breaking some user code so it had to be reverted back in the v1.9.x serie and likely it will have to wait for a v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Note: I tested this on Julia 1.9.4 on Windows)*

The expressions `1. /` and `1 ./` are different in that the first tokenizes to `1.` and `/` while the second tokenizes to `1` and `./`.

`1` and `1.` are numbers. The former is an integer, the latter is a floating point number.

The `./` operator, because of the `.` in front of it, is a *broadcast* operation, i.e. `/` applied to *each element* of something. `1 ./ [1,2,3]` is equivalent to `[1/1, 1/2, 1/3]`.

The `/` operator is *usually* division. On some types it is defined to be something else.

In Julia, lots of mathy things are defined to have mathy operators that operate on the entire object, not its elements. Example: `*` on matrices causes matrix multiplication, not elementwise multiplication (use `.*` for that).

Investigation with `@code_lowered 1 / [1, 2, 3]` reveals that the **pseudo-inverse** (`LinearAlgebra.pinv`) of the vector is calculated.

```
julia> @code_lowered 1 / [1, 2, 3]
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = LinearAlgebra.pinv(v)
│   %2 = x * %1
└──      return %2
)
```

Antonello and Oscar Smith have pointed out (see comments) that this specific behavior has been discussed and is likely to be removed in the future.

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/40758, https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/49915, and https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/50955  for details. `1/Vector` is an interpretation that likely should have been removed as part of 4774, but at this point can't to ensure backwards compatibility.